# Equivalent of Java's "LookingAt()" in .net?

Tags: .net, regex

Java has a regex function called "LookingAt()" which will allow partial matches against patterns, my question is:

Does .net have an equivalent of "LookingAt()"?

I may or may not use it for KeyPress validation but I just would like to know for future reference.

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: So you intend to prevent pasting from the clipboard, too? This would not even trigger a keypress event, when done with the mouse.

Comment: I could just call the validation on another event if I need to....that isn't really the issue

Comment: But what problem are you solving if your restriction can be circumvented so easily?

Comment: BTW you should not post anything to the answers section that is not itself an answer to your question. For comments use the comments function, for clarifications edit your original question directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've tidied my mess up!  As for the question I obviously left it far too open ended so I've reworded it.....thank you for your help

Comment: But LookingAt() is not originally meant to serve validation purposes, but rather is a way to see what the matcher is currently seeing. Can you post what you would do in Java, maybe your approach is not good itself? At least I can't see a way to sensibly use LookingAt() for the scenario you describe.

Comment: It shows that the string is currently matching the pattern and could therefore be used for validation as far as I can see...I'm not writing a financial system or anything so It really doesn't matter that the user could paste an incorrect value in, this would be picked up by the whole pattern match

Comment: What keeps you from checking the whole input against a regex on keypress and reject the last character if that failed? I somehow still can't see the advantage/point of using LoookingAt() here. But maybe I'm still not getting it. Can you include a minimal code sample demonstrating what you try to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `lookingAt()` is the correct model for what you're trying to do.  All it does is anchor the match to the beginning of the input, as if you had used the `^` start anchor at the beginning of your regex and called `find()`, and that would be trivial to emulate in .NET.

I think what you're trying to do is prevent users from entering invalid data.  For example, if a textfield expects a decimal number with two decimal places, your validation regex might be `\d+\.\d\d` . If a user starts by typing a digit, the regex doesn't match, but the digit *could* be part of a valid entry, so you let them keep on typing.  But if the user types 'z', you block it because there's no way it could be part of a valid entry.

In other words, you don't want to know if the regex matches part of the string, you want to know if the string matches part of the regex.  There is a way to do that in Java, using the `hitEnd()` method, but I don't think .NET has an equivalent for that.  In fact, I don't know of any other regex flavor that does.

But blocking users' keypresses is rather rude anyway, in my opinion.  I prefer to let them know by some other means that their input is invalid.  For example, you can display the contents of the textfield in red, or disable the button that they use to submit the entry (or both).  Each time something changes in the textfield, you check the contents against your (full) regex and update the state of the field and/or button accordingly.

Here's demonstration of `hitEnd()`:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("");
    String[] tests = { "5.99", "5", "@" };
    for (String s : tests)
    {
      if (m.reset(s).matches())
      {
        System.out.println("full match");
      }
      else if (m.hitEnd())
      {
        System.out.println("partial match");
      }
      else 
      {
        System.out.println("no match");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get "full match" for the first string, "partial match" for the second, and "no match" for the third.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt() - Thsi suggests that I could implement LookingAt for validation using a TextChanged event by providing a "so far so good" kind of response.  To be honest I should never have mentioned keypress validation I simply...

Comment: ...wanted to know if I could do a "so far so good" i.e. "the input is matching the pattern so far" feature using a LookingAt equivalent.  I appreciate the advice on the KeyPress validation and will have a think about it...that is outside the scope of my question though to be honest!

Comment: "So far so good" is an excellent description of what hitEnd() does; check out the demo I added to my answer. lookingAt() effectively means the opposite: the whole pattern matches the first part of the string, and any characters beyond the matched text are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the explanation of the difference.

Comment: @Alan: That's what I tried to explain to wheelibin all along. :-) +1 for the nice and complete answer.

Comment: @Tomalak, I wasn't asking for advice on how to design my validation though and you didn't actually answer my question whereas Alan did.....thanks for your input both of you.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant to your case, but in general this is not a good idea because some languages often need combined keys to enter chars: a "â" is often typed by keying ^ and a. If you only want to allow alphanumeric keys and want to include â, you might prevent their entering if you disallow ^.

Comment: Good point, however the application is an internal one and this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use to check an email address with regex. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for?

```
Regex emailregex = new Regex("(?<user>[^@]+)@(?<host>.+)");
        string s = "email@address.com";

        Match m = emailregex.Match(s);


        if (m.Success)
        {

        do something here


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to disable the key. You just have to find the keyCode for the key you are disabling this disables the return or enter key on the keyboard.

//This function disables the enter key so that the user can't enter a bunch of spaces. 
function kH(e) {
    var pK = e ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
    return pK != 13;
}
document.onkeypress = kH;
if (document.layers) document.captureEvents(Event.KEYPRESS);

Here is a page that lists all of the keycodes for your keyboard. 13 was for the enter key so in this function I am allowing all keys != to 13

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001686.html